# Vagrant error apache2 Could not start Service : Execution of '/etc/init.d/apache2 start'

Tags: php, apache2, vagrant, virtualbox

I was just working normally, restarted vagrant and this happened:

```
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Apache::Service/Service[httpd]: Failed to call refresh: Could not start Service[httpd]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/apache2 start' returned 1: 
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Apache::Service/Service[httpd]: Could not start Service[httpd]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/apache2 start' returned 1:
```

I've tried to re-install apache2 and vagrant then it shows the same error.

Comment: ssh into the vagrant box and try to start apache manually, check the apache logs for errors. Then ask again providing better info, maybe you did a software update or something in apache changed before you restarted your box